# pcaprub ошибка exit code 2

Tags: ruby

Пытаюсь использовать команду `bundle install` (Ruby), получаю следующее сообщение в (`pcaprub v0.12.4`):

```
[*] Running checks for pcaprub_c code...
platform is x64-mingw32
checking for -lws2_32... yes
checking for -liphlpapi... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock2.h... yes
checking for iphlpapi.h... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for pcap_open_live() in -lwpcap... no
checking for pcap_setnonblock() in -lwpcap... no
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.4/ext/pcaprub_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.4/ext/pcaprub_c
make "DESTDIR="
generating pcaprub_c-x64-mingw32.def
compiling pcaprub.c
In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/pcap/pcap.h:41:0,
                 from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/pcap.h:45,
                 from pcaprub.c:11:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/pcap-stdinc.h:64:0: warning: "snprintf" redefined
 #define snprintf _snprintf

In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2429:0,
                 from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from pcaprub.c:1:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/subst.h:6:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define snprintf ruby_snprintf

In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/pcap/pcap.h:41:0,
                 from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/pcap.h:45,
                 from pcaprub.c:11:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/pcap-stdinc.h:65:0: warning: "vsnprintf" redefined
 #define vsnprintf _vsnprintf

In file included from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2429:0,
                 from C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from pcaprub.c:1:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/subst.h:7:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define vsnprintf ruby_vsnprintf

pcaprub.c: In function 'rbpcap_each_data':
pcaprub.c:983:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   fno = (int)pcap_getevent(rbp->pd);
         ^
pcaprub.c:983:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   fno = (int)pcap_getevent(rbp->pd);
       ^
pcaprub.c: In function 'rbpcap_each_packet':
pcaprub.c:1025:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   fno = (int)pcap_getevent(rbp->pd);
         ^
pcaprub.c:1025:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   fno = (int)pcap_getevent(rbp->pd);
       ^
pcaprub.c: In function 'rbpcap_thread_wait_handle':
pcaprub.c:1265:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       rbpcap_thread_wait_handle_blocking,
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from pcaprub.c:4:0:
C:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/thread.h:28:7: note: expected 'void * (*)(void *)' but argument is of type 'VALUE (*)(void *) {aka long long unsigned int (*)(void *)}'
 void *rb_thread_call_without_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1,
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
linking shared-object pcaprub_c.so
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `pcap_findalldevs'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x299): undefined reference to `pcap_freealldevs'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupnet'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x41e): undefined reference to `pcap_close'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `pcap_dump_close'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x65d): undefined reference to `pcap_set_timeout'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `pcap_list_datalinks'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `pcap_datalink_val_to_name'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x74e): undefined reference to `pcap_free_datalinks'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x763): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x809): undefined reference to `pcap_datalink_name_to_val'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x876): undefined reference to `pcap_set_datalink'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x894): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x920): undefined reference to `pcap_set_snaplen'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x9b5): undefined reference to `pcap_set_promisc'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xac2): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupnet'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xb38): undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xb4e): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xb80): undefined reference to `pcap_setfilter'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xb90): undefined reference to `pcap_freecode'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xba2): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xbca): undefined reference to `pcap_freecode'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xc43): undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xc56): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xc7e): undefined reference to `pcap_freecode'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xcb0): undefined reference to `pcap_activate'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xd14): undefined reference to `pcap_close'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xdec): undefined reference to `pcap_close'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0xe24): undefined reference to `pcap_create'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x107d): undefined reference to `pcap_close'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x10ec): undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x127e): undefined reference to `pcap_open_offline'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x13f8): undefined reference to `pcap_open_dead'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1511): undefined reference to `pcap_dump_open'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x15b8): undefined reference to `pcap_dump_close'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x16fd): undefined reference to `pcap_dump'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x17c6): undefined reference to `pcap_sendpacket'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x17d9): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x18c9): undefined reference to `pcap_setnonblock'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x18f1): undefined reference to `pcap_dispatch'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x19dc): undefined reference to `pcap_setnonblock'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1a04): undefined reference to `pcap_dispatch'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1b14): undefined reference to `pcap_getevent'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1bc2): undefined reference to `pcap_getevent'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1c70): undefined reference to `pcap_datalink'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1cbb): undefined reference to `pcap_major_version'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1d06): undefined reference to `pcap_minor_version'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1d51): undefined reference to `pcap_snapshot'
pcaprub.o:pcaprub.c:(.text+0x1da9): undefined reference to `pcap_stats'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:259: pcaprub_c.so] Ошибка 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Использую команду для `Metasploit`:

`ruby c:\git\metasploit-framework\msfconsole`

Comment: https://github.com/pcaprub/pcaprub#requirements

Comment: И кто свою закрывашку забыл? Вопрос уже переведён на русский, отбой. :)